# Getting image url from RSS feed using simplepie

Tags: php, rss, simplepie

I am very new to php and simplepie. I would like to be able to use simplepie to store an image url to a variable. For my example, I will use the ebay rss feed (http://deals.ebay.com/feeds/rss). The image that I am trying to get the url of is in a `<image src=` tag. When i use the code

```
foreach ($feed->get_items() as $item):
?>
<?php echo $item->get_description(); ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

The image and description are shown, but I am unable to store the image url to a variable. How can I use simplepie to store an image url to a variable?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use DOM parser such as [SimpleHTML](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) like:

```
require_once('simple_html_dom.php');

foreach ($feed->get_items() as $item)
{
 $description =  $item->get_description();
 $desc_dom = str_get_html($description);
 $image = $desc_dom->find('img', 0);
 $image_url = $image->src;
}
```

It returns the URL of first image. If you want to get all images, you can store them in array like  `$desc_dom->find('img');`

If you are using **SimpleHTML** on composer projects, use

```
composer require mgargano/simplehtmldom
```

Comment: But is it a good idea to use both simple pie and DOM parser at the same time?

Comment: I think, there is no problem.

Comment: The code does work, but the page loads much slower. Is there a way to only use SimplePie and not SimpleHTML?

Comment: actually I haven't used SimplePie, but generally you can write function for getting image with regular expression too.

Comment: but I would prefer to use DOM parser instead of regex

Comment: Would you reccomend stop using simplepie and only using a DOM parser?

Comment: Also how can I view the url of the image, not the image itself?

Comment: since I haven't used SimplePie, I can't say anything. but in principle, it is possible parsing rss feed with DOM parser like SimpleHTML

Comment: foreach ($image_url as $element){
 echo $element->src;
}

Comment: if $image_url is not an array, I mean `$image_url = $desc_dom->find('img', 0);` then just use `$image_url->src`

Comment: Great thank you very much. The one last thing I liked about simplepie was the cache feature, so simplepie would only check for new rss posts every 30 mins. Is there a way to do this using DOM parser?

Comment: You're welcome. You can do this with `cron` feature of Linux.

Comment: Couldn't find this anywhere else. I was making my project which is due tomorrow and I just login to upvote your answer. You sir are awesome!
@ValehHajiyev